# US visa refusal after keeping the passport for 10 days

Tags: usa, visa-refusals

My husband and I applied for a US visa. I had an official visit to Canada and my husband was accompanying me for a week visit. After that, we were planning to go to the US for a 3-day weekend.

The visa officer took our passports and approved our visa. However, my passport came back after 3 days with the visa, but my husband's passport was returned after 8 days with a refusal letter stating that they were not convinced about his stay. We had taken with us all the documents, bank statements, itinerary, ITR for 3 years, NOC from Office, Employment letter, everything, but since the visa officer did not ask for any documents we could not show anything. Now he got a refusal. What do we do?

Comment: Is it worth doing anything else? Did you have anything you really needed to do in USA? If not it may be best to just accept the refusal.

Comment: Do you have other close family remaining behind in your home country? Can your husband accompany you to Canada? He appears not to have been able to overcome the assumption of immigrant intent, there is probably little or nothing you can do regarding the US refusal.

Comment: Did you apply for the US visa _in Canada_? It is usually more difficult to get approved for a US visa if you apply for a visa outside your home country.

Answer (score 1):

What your husband may be able to do will be set out in the refusal letter and, generally, cite the section of applicable US law (and not much more, so it may leave you unsure of how to proceed).

Your husband can re-apply and, without knowing under which section he was denied, it’s best that you refer to the [State Department guidance](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html). In most cases, the recourse is to overcome the objections raised, e.g., incomplete application or supporting documents (section 221(g) of INA), qualifications and immigrant intent (section 214(b) of INA).